# arrays and loops in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I have matlab script in which I am trying to read data from an array in a file globalbathy.dat.  Now I want to make a script that will read part of the array based on user input.  Therefore depending on the user input the script should be able to values from the array A[j,i] where the i components is from 260 to 300 and the j is from 50 to 0.  Below is the sample of the script:

```
function [lat_sub,lon_sub,depth_sub] = compute_data(coord,dx,dy)

lats = coord(1);
lons = coord(2);
late = coord(3);
lone = coord(4);

latss = lats;
lonss = lons;
lates = late;
lones = lone;

lat_sub = [latss:dy:lates];
lon_sub = [lonss:dx:lones];

Nx = length(lon_sub);
Ny = length(lat_sub);

Nb=Ny*Nx;


filename = 'globalbathy.dat';
delimiterIn = ' ';
headerlinesIn = 1;
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);

startlon = uint64(((80 - latss)*360) + lonss);
startlat = uint64((80 - latss));

endlon  = uint64(startlon+Nx);
endlat = uint64(startlat+Ny);

for i = startlon:endlon
   for j = startlat:endlat
     printf('i is %d and j is %d\n',i,j);
     disp(A.data(j,i));
   end;
 end;
 return;
```

However when the run the script, I get the following error:

```
error: A(0,_): subscripts must be either integers 1 to (2^31)-1 or logicals
error: called from
    compute_data at line 51 column 3
```

I was under the impression that i and j are integers.  How do you resolve this situation in order for me to get the values I want for array A?

Comment: Yes, integers that must be **strictly** greater than 0.

Comment: You don’t need to cast to an integer type for indexing, you can use normal doubles. But their values must not have a fractional part. Your problem is that you try to index element 0, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `i` and `j` must be integers.

You can approximate the value of `i` and `j` to integers using the `floor` function (e.g. `floor(0.1)` is `0` and `floor(0.9)` is `0` too):

```
for i = floor(startlon):floor(endlon)
    for j = floor(startlat):floor(endlat)
        printf('i is %d and j is %d\n',i,j);
        disp(A.data(j,i));
    end
end
```

Comment: OP has cast the indices to `uint64`, so `floor` will not do anything. OP’s problem is using 0 to index, whereas indices start at 1.

Comment: You're right. I don't understand why it is necessary the `uint64` conversion

Comment: `A` is an array indexable with integers. I don't understand how the indexes `i` and `j` are related to it.

Comment: You might want to ask these questions as comments to the question, so that OP gets notified.